# Applications of compact braided monodial categories

Tags: category-theory, math-history, applications, braidings

In this paper by Baez http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/rosetta.pdf I read (page 3) that ‘compact braided monoidal categories’ became very relevant for Physics in the 90s....Could anyone provide me with some illustration of that, examples proving the claim?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think, Quantum Field Theory or related field can be in connection. Hopf Monoids can be defined in braided monoidal categories, and they model the grouplike operation of certain quantities when particles interact..